# Z3Py: How should I represent some 32-bit; 16-bit and 8-bit registers?

Tags: z3, z3py

I am a newbie to `Z3`. Sorry if it is a stupid question..

I am basically trying to implement a simple symbolic execution engine on `x86-32bit` assembly instructions. Here is the problem I am facing now:

Suppose before execution, I have initialize some registers by using `BitVec`.

```
self.eq['%eax']  = BitVec('reg%d' % 1, 32)
self.eq['%ebx']  = BitVec('reg%d' % 2, 32)
self.eq['%ecx']  = BitVec('reg%d' % 3, 32)
self.eq['%edx']  = BitVec('reg%d' % 4, 32)
```

So here is my question, how to handle some `16-bit` or even `8-bit` registers?

Is there anyway I can extract a `8-bit` part from a 32-bit `BitVec`, assigning it with some value, and then put it back? Can I do that in `z3`? Or is there any better way..?

Am I clear? thank you a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract parts of a bitvector which results in a new, smaller bitvector value that you can use any way you like (for example add).

You can replace parts of a bitvector by first extracting all the parts and then concatenating smaller bitvectors into one big one.

For example incrementing the upper half of eax would be like this:

```
eaxNew = concat(add(extract(eaxOld, upperHalf), 1), extract(eaxOld, lowerHalf))
```

(Pseudo-code)

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/namespacez3py.html